# BIGQUERY SELECT list expression references column CHANNEL_ID which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [10:13]

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing this error:

> BIGQUERY SELECT list expression references column CHANNEL_ID which is
>   neither grouped nor aggregated at [10:13]

I don't know why it's caused,Can someone explain it to me?

Here are my codes:

```
SELECT 
    t0.CHANNEL_ID,
    t1.CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NAME
FROM
    (SELECT
         TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, MONTH) as `DATE`,
         CHANNEL_ID
     FROM 
         `pops-204909.yt_kids.p_content_owner_basic_a3_yt_kids`   
     WHERE 
         DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) between "2017-08-01" and "2017-08-31"
     GROUP BY 
         `DATE`) t0
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, MONTH) as `DATE`,
         CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NAME
     FROM 
         `pops-204909.yt_kids.p_content_owner_ad_revenue_raw_a1_yt_kids`
     WHERE 
         DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) between "2017-08-01" and "2017-08-31"
     GROUP BY 
         `DATE`) t1 ON t0.DATE = t1.DATE
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` - all expressions in the respective SELECT list must be either those which are in the GROUP BY or should be with AGGREGATION function - like MIN, MAX etc. See more about [`GROUP BY` clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group-by-clause)

So in your case both sub-queries are missing respectively `CHANNEL_ID` and `CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NAME` in the respective `GROUP BY`. Or depends on your logic they should come with some aggregation function.

Note: Above explains the error you see. Rather than this - you query makes no much sense to me even if you will fix that specific error - but I hope you have something in mind :o)

Comment: Right! I deleted the  GROUP BY row then i queried successfully! About your note, what do you mean by that? Why it makes no sense?

Comment: I meant that based on your example - joining just by date makes no much sense to me, but as I said - you might have something in mind here

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(sum(unitprice*quantity),2) as sales, extract(month from orderdate) as month from `adyy.orders_details` od join `adyy.orders` o on o.orderid=od.orderid
group by extract(month from orderdate)
order by extract(month from orderdate)
```

Even after the query being right, as soon as i put `order by` clause this error poops up.

I think there is some glitch in big query. sometimes it behaves random.