# Keep variables in the SELECT list which are not used in the GROUP BY nor aggregated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: table1 (including id, title, and abstract) and table2 (including id, pubdate, and family_id).

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

Each id is unique but multiple rows can have the same family_id.

My goal is to display the id, title and pubdate only for the MIN(pubdate) of each family_id so that I should get:

[image: Result]

I tried this:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.title, nt2.pubdate
FROM
  (SELECT
     id, family_id, MIN(pubdate) AS pubdate
   FROM
     table2
   GROUP BY
     family_id) AS nt2
INNER JOIN
  table1 t1
ON
  t1.id = nt2.id
```

I get the following error message in BigQuery: "*SELECT list expression references column id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [position]*".

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360162/bigquery-select-list-expression-references-column-channel-id-which-is-neither-gr?rq=1) that this is due to the fact that all expressions in the respective SELECT list must be either those which are in the GROUP BY or should be with AGGREGATION function.

But, I do need id for merging with table1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you want an [analytic function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the “Group by” statement, you need to write all the fields you use in the “SELECT” statement. You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause).

Like this line of code:

```
GROUP BY Family_id,id
```

In this case, if the family and id are duplicated in another field, they will group.

Here is an example code:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.title, nt2.pubdate
FROM
  (
  Select B.* 
  from (
        SELECT
        family_id, MIN(pubdate) AS pubdate
        FROM
            table2
        GROUP BY
            family_id
      ) as A 
        inner join table2  B on A.pubdate = B.pubdate and A.family_id=B.family_id
    ) AS nt2
INNER JOIN
  table1  t1
ON
  t1.id = nt2.id
```

Comment: Your solution does not work. If I apply this, it will select id, title and pubdate for all id from 1 to 5 which is not what I want this I need to select only id 1, 3 and 5. I completed my question with some illustrations of the tables and the result I need.

Comment: hi, already change the query, In the subquery, you need to use only these fields min(pubdate) and family_id and group by only using this two fields. And use join with table2 to get the id of the table.  Ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok, now it works. So, the solution is to add an extra INNER JOIN to get the id for merging with table 1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems that you can have one `id`  with multiple `pubdate` in  `table2`
then, you have to pick the `id` associated with the oldest `pubdate` adding it into the `group by` clause and it won't affect the id.
try

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.title, nt2.pubdate
FROM
  (SELECT
     id, family_id, MIN(pubdate) AS pubdate
   FROM
     table2
   GROUP BY
     id, family_id) AS nt2
INNER JOIN
  table1 t1
ON
  t1.id = nt2.id
```

and you will have your oldest `id`, `title` and `pubdate` for each `family_id` *(the latter won't appear in your final table as long as you do not put it in the select clause)*

Comment: You understood my point but, as the previous solution, it does not work. If I apply this, it will select id, title and pubdate for all id from 1 to 5 which is not what I want this I need to select only id 1, 3 and 5. I completed my question with some illustrations of the tables and the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select id, title, pubdate
from table2 
join table1 using(id)
where true 
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by family_id order by pubdate)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I get a syntax error on the last line.

Comment: if you run above query as is - you would not get any error! have you modified query? what exactly error you got?

Comment: No, I did not modified anything. I get a syntax error in MySQL 5.6 but I could not say more about it. Here, this is a link to a online SQL testing website with my data example and your code: https://sqltest.net/#1489401

Comment: so why you tag your question with bigquery then?