# Google BigQuery: How to filter out rows by a particular column's value frequency

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say that I only want to return rows where a column value occurs at least twice.

I would do something like

```
SELECT 
table1.columnA
from table1
GROUP BY 
table1.columnA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

That works for just one column, but if I want to do return several columns but only have the filter apply to one column, it doesn't work. My attempt is

```
SELECT 
table1.columnA,
table1.columnB,
from table1
GROUP BY 
table1.columnA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Which gives a "ColumnB which is neither GROUPED nor AGGREGATED " error.

From this post, it seems that I need to have all values in SELECT to be grouped or aggregated, but I only one to filter by one particular column

[BIGQUERY SELECT list expression references column CHANNEL_ID which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [10:13]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360162/bigquery-select-list-expression-references-column-channel-id-which-is-neither-gr)

So I'm still trying to figure out a way to filter by value frequency for a particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function to count frequency and then filter. For example:

```sql
select distinct 
    columnA,
    columnB
from
    (select 
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by columnA) as rn 
     from table1)
where rn > 2
```

Let me know, if it is still not working for you.

Comment: I believe I am setting it up correctly but I am getting '400 unrecognized name: table1

Comment: It is a subquery (my bad), so try to select distinct columns without table name) @SantoshGupta7 (I've fixed it in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

te problem is as always if you only group by columnA and there are multiple values for every row in te grouped columA, you need to choose which you want of the columnB

```
MIN(colunsB) would take the smalest row in the group of columA.
```

it would return so for every row in te grouped columa only one row of columnb, the smallest one.

in case that every row in columna has only one row in columnb

```
coluanA columnB
ab      cd
ab      cd
ab1     cd1
ab1     cd1
ab1     cd1
```

you should make `GROUP BY columnA,colmunB` as it will only return 1 row

Te basic idea of GRouping is that you want an aggreagtion of the rest of  the columns

Comment: I guess grouping won't work in my case then, as I was only trying to use it to filter a column's frequency

Comment: you need to determine what grouped expressiion you want from colmnB. a result set is a,ways unsorted by definition, and so withput aggegration functions wou will not get an deterministic answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to filter out rows using **columnA**'s frequency, below query would be a most simple solution.

> I guess grouping won't work in my case then, as I was only trying to use it to filter a column's frequency

```sql
 SELECT columnA, columnB
   FROM table1
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA) > 2
```