# BIGQUERY : SELECT list expression references column date which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, database, select, google-bigquery

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT
 EXTRACT(YEAR from date) AS year,team, scorer, penalty,
 COUNT(scorer) AS repeated_names
FROM `data-analytics-project-392406.football.goalscorers`)
WHERE
 repeated_names > 1
GROUP BY
 year, team, scorer, penalty
ORDER BY
 year DESC
```

I wanted to get the names repeating more than once, and this error came up

//problem is showing in 4th line "date"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BIGQUERY SELECT list expression references column CHANNEL\_ID which is neither grouped nor aggregated at \[10:13\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360162/bigquery-select-list-expression-references-column-channel-id-which-is-neither-gr)

Comment: Your GROUP BY needs to be in your inner SELECT, where your aggregate function is. Or you need to completely restructure your query - depending on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 EXTRACT(YEAR from date) AS year, team, scorer, penalty,
 COUNT(scorer) AS repeated_names
FROM `data-analytics-project-392406.football.goalscorers`
GROUP BY
 year, team, scorer, penalty
HAVING
 count(scorer) > 1
ORDER BY
 year DESC
```